# Delete listview items in custom adapter

Tags: android-listview, custom-adapter

I'm sorry for this question, but I'm a new in Android developing. I searched in internet, but I don't found any appropriate answer. I have a following code in my custom adapter:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, false);

}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    viewHolder.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("title")));
    viewHolder.publishDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date_time")));
    viewHolder.rssNewsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.rssnews);

}

@Override
public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
            R.layout.listview_rssreaderactivity_row, arg2, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.title = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.tw_title_listview_row_main);
    viewHolder.publishDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tw_pubDate_listview_row_main);
     viewHolder.rssNewsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageRssView);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView publishDate;
    ImageView rssNewsImage;

}
 }
```

I want to delete listView item in my custom adapter. Here is my code for click events:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         final int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder itemLongClickdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            RssNewsActivity.this);
    itemLongClickdialog.setItems(R.array.array_longclick_item,
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   }
   });
```

I can't delete given item.
How to resolve this problem? I will appreciate all answers.

Comment: I found how to delete item in my listView: I added the following code in onItemClick method: ((SmartRSSApp) getApplication()).getItemsDB().deleteNews(id);      getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_SHOW_NEWS_FEEDS, null, RssNewsActivity.this);

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
  // User clicked OK button
  ItemsAdapter dba = new ItemsAdapter (yourActivity); 
 dba.open();
 dba.remove(_id); 
 Log.i("TAAG", "removed: "+_id);
 dba.close();
 cursor.requery();
 listview.getadaper().notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
 });
```

Comment: or just reset the adapter after deleting from DB